# Almacenar contraseñas

Tags: android, login

Tengo una duda... Estoy haciendo una app con Android Studio y en la Activity inicial hay un login que comprueva a través de una consulta a un servidor si el usuario es correcto o no. Hasta aquí todo bien. Pero mi duda viene cuando implemento un boton switch para que el usuario pueda guardar su usario y contraseña. Entiendo que es una mala praxis guardar usuarios y contraseñas en el almacenamiento del mismo dispositivo. Pero no se cual puede ser la solucion para usar el método de recordar usuario y contraseña con el switch y no almacenarlo en local...

Actualmente almaceno el usuario y contraseña con Realm.

Alguna propuesta?

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Puedes almacenar en SharedPreferences que es propio de android.

Comment: Hola @Ferran recuerda que es importante agregar lo que trataste, recuerda realizar tus preguntas en base a [ask], saludos.

Comment: Gracias @Bicho pero en SharedPreferences tambien se guardan los datos en texto plano, no? Tampoco es muy seguro... Creo...

Comment: Si los encriptas antes de almacenar es seguro.

Comment: Lo ideal es que guardes un token de acceso, no el usuario y la contraseña

Comment: Puedes la librería nativa DataStore que ya se encarga de la encriptación, hay codelab de Google https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore Ahora bien, como te comentan, si puedes tener OAuth2 con access y refresh token, mejor... pero al final tendrás que persistir igualmente el token así que el DataStore te vendrá bien.